# SQL View - Nesting SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I am trying to create a view from the following table.  I'm looking for the output to be the CUSTOMER, the most recent or MAX(CALENDARDT) for that CUSTOMER and a SUM(QTY) field, for all records that have the same CCYYMM field as the MAX(CALENDARDT) record.

Expected result would be

```
1500627 03/25/2013 5
```

5 being the sum of the qty field for the last two records both with 201303 in the CCYYMM field

```
Customer  |CCYYMM   |CalendarDt|DocNumb|Qty
1500627 |201202 |02/01/2012|Z201202|0
1500627 |201203 |03/02/2012|2542484|7
1500627 |201205 |05/04/2012|2979222|3
1500627 |201206 |06/20/2012|3262548|2
1500627 |201207 |07/31/2012|3500794|1
1500627 |201208 |08/30/2012|6946730|1
1500627 |201209 |09/13/2012|3774092|1
1500627 |201210 |10/31/2012|4063932|3
1500627 |201211 |11/16/2012|Z201211|0
1500627 |201301 |01/04/2013|Z201301|0
1500627 |201301 |01/30/2013|Z201301|0
1500627 |201303 |03/01/2013|4876779|1
1500627 |201303 |03/25/2013|5044331|4
```

Comment: I think you could use a subquery with HAVING. Aggregates can't be in the WHERE clause without one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. The inner SELECT is used to get the max date per customer and that is JOINed back to the original table:

```
SELECT MyTable.Customer, 
       MaxDates.MaxDate,
       SUM(Qty) AS TotalQuantity
FROM MyTable
JOIN (SELECT Customer, 
             MAX(CalendarDT) AS MaxDate
      FROM MyTable
      GROUP BY Customer) AS MaxDates
    ON MaxDates.Customer = MyTable.Customer
    AND MaxDates.MaxDate = MyTable.CalendarDT
GROUP BY MyTable.Customer, MaxDates.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with judicious use of window functions:

```
select customer, calendardt, sumqty
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer order by calendardt desc) as seqnum,
             sum(qty) over (partition by ccyymm) as sumqty
      from followingtable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that this assumes that the phrase:  " SUM(QTY) field, for all records that have the same CCYYMM field as the MAX(CALENDARDT) record" applies across *all* customers, not just the one customer.  If you want to limit it to the one customer, you can make this modification:

```
select customer, calendardt, sumqty
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer order by calendardt desc) as seqnum,
             sum(qty) over (partition by customer, ccyymm) as sumqty
      from followingtable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```